# API Connect docker gateway on localhost throwing ECONNREFUSED

Tags: loopback, apiconnect

I'm running the below node/npm/apic versions.

```
$node -v
v6.14.4
$npm -v
6.4.1
$apic -v
API Connect: v5.0.8.5-iFix (apiconnect: v3.0.25)

apiconnect-init-datapower-gateway@1.0.3
```

**Problem:** I am able to start the API on port 4001 and the datapower gw on port 4002. But getting the below error on the console. When I hit https://127.0.0.1:4002, I get a 404 not found. Any help would be appreciated? Thanks!

```
$apic services
Service test-api running on port 4001. Access the application dashboard at http://127.0.0.1:4001/appmetrics-dash
Service test-api-gw running on port 4002.

$apic edit
Express server listening on http://127.0.0.1:4001
loopback deprecated loopback#context middleware is deprecated. See https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Using%20current%20context for more details. ../../../../../../../.nvm/versions/node/v6.14.4/lib/node_modules/apiconnect/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/rest.js:60:32
Building datapower-mgmt-server-lite
Step 1/13 : FROM node:6-alpine
 ---> dfc29bfa7d41
Step 2/13 : RUN apk add --no-cache openssl
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a985e7c62de2
Step 3/13 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> de637a1c8cb9
Step 4/13 : COPY ./package.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6783f3e99010
Step 5/13 : COPY ./apim-lite lib/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cbedb90bcefc
Step 6/13 : COPY ./common common/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 97c2c5b69e75
Step 7/13 : ARG IBM_APICONNECT_NPM_REGISTRY
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 200299d96559
Step 8/13 : ENV npm_config_registry ${IBM_APICONNECT_NPM_REGISTRY:-https://registry.npmjs.com}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4df68f6d1eba
Step 9/13 : RUN npm install --prod --quiet --depth 0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c64e5f33e3b8
Step 10/13 : ENV NODE_ENV production
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8dc4cde17120
Step 11/13 : RUN mkdir -p /tmp/generated && chown node:node /tmp/generated
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 43d2b4ea51ff
Step 12/13 : USER node
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1eeb74a34016
Step 13/13 : CMD [ "node", "lib/server.js" ]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 54b6327414db
Successfully built 54b6327414db
Successfully tagged ibm-apiconnect-toolkit/datapower-mgmt-server-lite:1.1.10
Building datapower-api-gateway
Step 1/7 : FROM ibmcom/datapower:7.6.0.0.289959
 ---> ba469cb4cbd3
Step 2/7 : ENV  DATAPOWER_ACCEPT_LICENSE=true      DATAPOWER_INTERACTIVE=true
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 57802d96884a
Step 3/7 : COPY config /drouter/config
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 343a6a7c27ad
Step 4/7 : COPY local /drouter/local
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 73fdb13773ec
Step 5/7 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e0aa0bae38d6
Step 6/7 : RUN set-user drouter
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 784be61a92cc
Step 7/7 : USER drouter
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c872a6ed1d13
Successfully built c872a6ed1d13
Successfully tagged ibm-apiconnect-toolkit/datapower-api-gateway:1.1.10
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:64802
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1099:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 64802 }
```

Noticing these errors in the docker container logs:

```
20200128T044825.955Z [apiconnect][0x00330019][mgmt][error] source-http(webapi-http): tid(111): Operation state transition to up failed
20200128T044940.830Z [apiconnect][0x00330019][mgmt][error] source-http(webapi-internal-local): tid(111): Operation state transition to up failed
20200128T044940.854Z [apiconnect][0x00330019][mgmt][error] source-https(webapi-https): tid(111): Operation state transition to up failed
```